# Ads array in tableview out of index

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, admob, ads

I have 3 arrays of data. I want to show ads after every 5 user cells in the table.

```
var nativeAds = [GADNativeAd]()
var item = [NewsElement]()
var filterItem = [NewsElement]()
```

After displaying 5 cells with ads, the application crashes with an error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

How do I re-add ads to the array or select an array with ads again?
There are smart guys sitting here, please help me. Thank you in advance!

below is my code

```
extension NewsViewController: GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate {
    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(adLoader) failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        print("Received native ad: \(nativeAd)")
        nativeAds.append(nativeAd)
    }
    
    func adLoaderDidFinishLoading(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader) {
        newsTblView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

```
extension NewsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    private func dataRow(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int? {
        let (quotient, remainder) = (indexPath.row + 1).quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: numAdsToLoad)
        if remainder == 0 { return nil }
        return quotient * (numAdsToLoad - 1) + remainder - 1
    }
    
    private func adRow(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int? {
        let (quotient, remainder) = (indexPath.row + 1).quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: numAdsToLoad)
        if remainder != 0 { return nil }
        return quotient - 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchActive {
            return filterItem.count
        } else {
            return item.count + nativeAds.count
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let row = dataRow(for: indexPath) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell
            if searchActive {
                let items = filterItem[row]
                cell.configCell(model: items )
            } else {
                let items = item[row]
                cell.configCell(model: items )
            }
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
            return cell
        } else if let row = adRow(for: indexPath) {
            let nativeAd = nativeAds[row]   <-- "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"
            nativeAd.rootViewController = self
            let nativeAdCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UnifiedNativeAdCell", for: indexPath) as! GADNativeAdViewCell
            nativeAdCell.setAdData()
            return nativeAdCell
        }
        fatalError("Did not find data or ad for cell: Should never get here")
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very fragile and the math you use isn't easy to follow since there are so many unknowns. what is numAdsToLoad for instance and how many elements do you have in the nativeAds array, is it constant or changing somehow?

Comment: numAdsToLoad = 5. nativeAds array is constant.

Comment: So if you have 10 items then 2 ads will be shown, right? But tableView(numberOfRowsInSection:) will return 15 an not 12.

Comment: No, my array fills 50 cells, and ad fills 5 cells when my table has to show 6 cells with ad, the application crashes. I need to re-select the array with advertising or re-add ads to the array

Comment: Like I said, there is so much info missing here so it's very hard to help.